# running shell script with expect for logging

Tags: shell, expect

I Have created a shell script as given below.This script will login to  a remote server as a normal user then switch to root user for creating a directory.The script is as given below.

> ssh -t qbadmin@10.3.2.0 '
>   su root -c "
>    echo \"Give Directory name :\";
>    read dir;
>    mkdir \$dir;
>   ";
>   '

Here the script will ask Password for normal user first.Then again it will ask for root Password.How could I automate this using `expect` command.I want to supply the password automatically for the root user only.I think it can be done with `expect`.

Please do help me.

Comment: What do you mean by *I want to supply the password automatically for the root user only*? Why don't you `ssh root@10.3.2.0` directly? `root` is not allowed to SSH?

Comment: In this case login to remote machine as root user through ssh is disabled by editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file in the remote machine.(by putting "no" for PermitRootLogin in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, we can disable root login through ssh in the specified machine )

Comment: Then you can consider configuring password-less SSH login for user *qbadmin*.

Comment: Is there any other way for supplying password for `su` command at same time need password for user `qbadmin` also !

Comment: Not quite clear what you are going to do. :(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `sudo` instead?  You could simply add 'qbadmin' in remote `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
qbadmin ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Then:

```
ssh -t qbadmin@10.3.2.0 '
echo \"Give Directory name :\";
read dir;
sudo mkdir \$dir;
'
```

Comment: Here I need to supply passwords automatically using `expect` for `su root -c`